# In Tornado, is multiple AsyncHTTPTestCase.fetch() possible?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tornado

I'm using `AsyncHTTPTestCase.fetch()` to get a response synchronously; in the method's body, `self.stop` is passed as a request completion callback to a `self.http_client.fetch()`. Moreover, `self.http_client` is assigned only once, in `__init__`, and is never reassigned.

So I conclude only one `fetch()` call is possible per test. Is this correct?

Is this intended, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple calls to `fetch()` in one test are definitely possible. In fact, [AsyncTestCase's documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/testing.html#asynchronous-test-cases) states *"It is possible to have multiple wait/stop cycles in the same test."*.

The reason that it is possible is that `AsyncHTTPTestCase.fetch()` calls `AsyncTestCase.wait()` and it is the call to `wait()` that (re)starts the IOLoop. In short, `wait()` [runs the IOLoop until `self.stop()` is called](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/testing.html#AsyncHTTPTestCase.wait).

Comment: Thank you, it made me re-read it once again. I see it that multiple calls to `new AsyncHTTPClient(self.io_loop).fetch()` are possible, but not to `myAsyncHTTPTestCase.fetch()`. Example in `AsyncHTTPTestCase` documentation is creating a new `Client` for each request.